# XP restarts the machine on boot over grub2 menu

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub2

There were two HDD attached on computer board.

One hdd has Linux installation and the other one has Windows XP (on first partition) and Windows 7 (on second partition)

First I installed xp and then 7. When computer boots up with just one HDD connected, both windows can boot up without any problem.

When I connect Linux HDD to any SATA port, and change bios settings as the primary boot disk; After loading grub menu I select Windows 7, and then I Windows Boot Loader menu came up. Then I select XP on windows boot loader and bom! Computer restarts when I press enter.

I have re-install that OSes in same sequence but result doesn't changed.

Comment: Disable restart on BSOD in XP and give it a try

Comment: Computer restarts anyway. Does not display BSOD.

Answer (score 0):

First you installed XP and then 7... on HDA.  That's the first and primary hard drive.  Their partitions get referenced by the bootloader on that drive with the information that they are installed on HDA.

Then, you connect the Linux HD, and you change the BIOS settings to make that drive the primary drive... namely making it HDA.  This makes the Windows drive HDB.

You reinstalled the OSes in same sequence?  What?

Look.  Change the Windows drive to be the primary again.  Leave the Linux drive in the computer.  Make sure you can boot to both versions of Windows... don't worry about Linux yet.  Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and fix your bootloader to allow you to boot to all the Operating Systems.

Comment: I need to add some information. Windows hdd always connected to sata1 never changed the that hdd port. It was also connected on sata1 while windows installations. I've change just Linux HDD port. But it was installed on sata0 in the first time. I try other ports and boot orders for while added linux hdd into system.

Comment: I understand if does not boot when I change the windows hdd port. But I thought HDD boot order logic were different from changing sata port. I thought it does not affects disk order but boot order.

Comment: @RecNes it affects it because the hard drive is no longer the same device.  HDA is the primary, HDB is the secondary, etc.  If you change which drive is primary, it is no longer HDA.  The Boot lloader is written with the exact devices in mind.  It's no different than if you were to re-arrange the partitions without rewriting the boot loader.

Comment: I tried the modify windows XP boot.ini file for secondery hdd but it does not work. However I don't want to install 3rd party boot loader on my system but I'm going to give a try tonight to EBCD.